# Shell script to replace the string and write it to the file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a Result.csv file where there are three columns. First contains the numeric value, Second and the third columns have the server name and the database name.
Like :
132424     Apollo_54    P_ARD_65

So instead of the P_ARD_65 i need to replace the string with P_PBD_65 and then i need to use this value in the connection string to connect to the database:
i am using .

```
mv Result.csv Result.csv.$$
sed 's/P_ARD/P_PBD/g' Result.csv.$$
mv Result.csv.$$ Result.csv
```

But it giving the error message.

I tried with :

```
mv Result.csv Result.csv.$$
sed 's/P_ARD/P_PBD/g' Result.csv.$$
Result.csv.$$ >> Result.csv
```

But the same error.

Please help.

Comment: Show us the error message...

Comment: Hi, I tried with sed 's/old_string/new_string/g' < Result.csv >> Result1.csv. It worked but on the verge of the extra file creation.

Comment: @10hero If you don't want extra file created, you can always do `sed '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

`$ sed -i "s|string|replacement|" file.csv`

I think all you were missing is the `-i` flag -- in this case, you don't need the `/g`

For multiple files:

`find ./path/to/files/ -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i "s|search|replace|" {} +`

if you just need to do the one file, and your `sed` is too old for `-i` - you can use this vi/vim command:

`:%s/search/replace/g`

Comment: Hi, I tried with the sed -i command. But the shell I am using might not support this option.

Comment: try that in vi or vim.